# How to use POST method in Appcelerator Titanium for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I have used the POST method in Titanium for Android app and it is working fine. But in iPhoen Simulator it shows a blank array in the server side to be posted.

Comment: Did you alloc your array?

Answer (score 1):

```
var req = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    timeout : 15000
});
req.open("POST", url);
req.onload = function(e) {
  //YOUR CODE HERE 
}
req.onerror = function(e) {
  //YOUR CODE HERE 
}
req.send(params);
```

If, server requires json format of data than you can use req.send(JSON.stringify(params)) otherwise you can send it simply.